# How to remove Pdf metadata using Microsoft PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pdf, metadata

Is there any way to remove Pdf meta data using PowerShell? Found some solutions using iTextsharp.dll but I'm looking for a solution that should work on windows and Mac OS.

Comment: [iText](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext) supports .NET Standard 2.0, so it should also run on macOS. Note the licensing model.

Comment: Is it must to download iText dll to remove metadata? Is that not possible just with PowerShell?

Comment: PowerShell has no built-in support for PDFs, so, yes, you'll need a third-party library.

Comment: Good point, @KJ: there is a [`IText7Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/IText7Module) PowerShell module that wraps the aforementioned library, but it was last updated in Oct 2022 as of this writing, and it's unclear what version of that library it wraps.

Comment: Meanwhile I tried this approach but didn't work
[remove metadata via PdfSharp](https://gist.github.com/righettod/d7e07443c43d393a39de741a0d920069)

Comment: @Sukhjeevan, I suggest finding a module / library that is documented to support what you're trying to do, and if you find that it doesn't, update your question (or close this one and create a new one) with a concrete solution attempt and a description of what, specifically, didn't work.

Comment: @KJ With PdfSharp I'm able to achieve this. Basically I need to change the Owner property and with that example it's working now. I created C# console app.